# Drilldown to specific Total in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, drilldown

Dear Fellow Stackoverflow-ians,

I come to you with another problem. I'm creating a drilldown on a varying PivotTable by VBA. I'm looking to drilldown on the Total cell always, and referring to it as i did in my code doesn't work when my PivotTable expands. How do i refer to a cell in my PivotTable without using a Cell-refering.

Code is as following:

```
Sheets("16-Compliancy-Extract").Select
Range("H14").Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Selection.Copy
```

H14 is the cell i'm referring to. Problem is that this Cell-"Adress" keeps changing when i'm dumping new data in to the PivotTable.

How do i name it decently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this: Where it searches for the last filled cell in the same column as my GrandTotal, which i was trying to retreive.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set pt = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Extract").PivotTables("Draaitabel1")
Set rng = pt.ColumnRange
rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).End(xlDown).ShowDetail = True
```